# A basis for the image of $f$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $f: \mathbb{R^4} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear transformation defined by $f(a,b,c,d)=a+b+c+d$. Find a basis for the $Im(f)$.

So, $Im(f)=\{f(a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R}: (a,b,c,d) \in \mathbb{R^4} \}$.

Then $Im(f)=\{a+b+c+d \in \mathbb{R}: a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R} \}=\mathbb{R}$.

I know that $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of the real numbers on the real line. That real line can be any axis of the plane, space or other higher dimension.

So, its correct to say that a basis for $\mathbb{R}$ can be any single vector of a canonical basis of any $n$ dimensional space?

For instance, can $\{(1,0,0)\}$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}$? Or $\{(0,1,0)\}$? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simpler than that. $\mathbb R$ is a one-dimensional vector space. So any nonzero "vector" will be a basis. For example, $\{1\}$ is a basis for the image of $f$. So are $\{-2\}$, $\{\pi/7\}$ and $\{102.35\}$.

Answer (score 0):

if $\operatorname{im}(f)=\Bbb{R}^1$ then $\dim_\Bbb{R}(\operatorname{im}(f))=\dim_\Bbb{R}(\Bbb{R}^1)=1$, therefore a basis for the $\operatorname{im}(f)$ is a basis for $\Bbb{R}^1$

**Hint**: let be $\{b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4\}$ a basis for $\Bbb{R}^4$, for example "[standard basis](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standardbasis#Standardbasis_in_den_Standardr.C3.A4umen)", then $\operatorname{im}(f)=f(\Bbb{R}^4)=\operatorname{Span}(f(b_1),f(b_2),f(b_3),f(b_4))$